# He says he is taking a nap but Facebook Messenger say online 1 minute ago

Tags: facebook-messenger

My boyfriend says he will take a nap and that is fine with me. After half an hour, I checked if I have messages from him only to find out that he was online 1 minute ago.

I asked him but he says that he is taking a nap and he did not turn off his phone, that's why it says last online 1 minute ago.

Is this true? Is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

Facebook Messenger statuses aren't accurate. My fiancé and I had the same problem. When he says he's going to work but yet after a couple of hours it'll still say he's "active now". As he never brings his phone to work, I called his work place and confirmed he arrived on time and was clearly working. There are a few times that both of us are in the same room and checked each other's status in Messenger, it'll say "active now" although our phones are offline or charging. The app isn't accurate so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

Some browser extensions or websites may also trigger Facebook activity. Or mouse movement if he is using Pidgin or an XMPP messenger.

Answer (score -1):

He may have you on "hide conversation". I checked this multiple times with my friends and that's exactly what it looks like. Facebook as a piece of code receives conflicting signals, because it knows it's supposed to show this user "offline", as he hid you, but the site can't relate to the time when he supposedly left - because he didn't - so it shows "online 1 minute ago" as a compromise.

Facebook deals very well with inactive users and, if you don't use it for some time, it will automatically render you offline. I often have this problem with my boyfriend, because we see each other offline even when we are in the same room, both obviously online - but it shows otherwise when we switch tabs to something else, despite keeping Facebook open.

In general, Facebook does a ton of lying and errors about statuses. So your bf might be telling the truth about leaving the phone on. But if these naps happen too often and at weird times, he's simply hiding you from his chat. Whatever the reason.

Answer (score -1):

The only reason I have seen for Facebook to display "Active 1 minute ago” is if you cannot see that person on chat. There would be two possible reasons for this:

1. That person has turned off chat on the device they are using. They will still be able to receive messages, but will show as offline. If they turned off chat in the Messenger app, they will actually still be able to chat; they simply won’t show up as Active Now.
2. That person has you blocked on chat.

There are bugs involving “Active Now” where someone will show Active for hours after closing Facebook, even if they’re not using an XMPP client (which should have been entirely phased out as of this answer). However, to the best of my knowledge they are a separate issue from what this question is about.

Still, it is very much possible that there are bugs I am unaware of concerning “1 minute ago.”